# Как записать текущее местоположение в Telegram bot в базу данных.

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Необходимо реализовать подписку на ежедневный прогноз погоды. Не получатся "захватить" параметры для текущего местоположения при команде "/subscribe".

Вот кусок кода:

```
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    if (update.hasMessage()) {
        String command = update.getMessage().getText();
        Message message = update.getMessage();

        long chat_id = update.getMessage().getChatId();

        Float latitude = message.getLocation().getLatitude();
        Float longitude = message.getLocation().getLongitude();

        if (message.hasLocation()) {
            SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
            String weatherResponse = "";
            //текущая погода
            try {
                weatherResponse = Weather.getInstance().currentWeather(latitude, longitude);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            sendMessage.setText(weatherResponse);
            sendMessage.setChatId(chat_id);

            try {
                execute(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //прогноз погоды на ближайшие сутки
            try {
                weatherResponse = Weather.getInstance().forecastWeather(latitude, longitude);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            sendMessage.setText(weatherResponse).setChatId(chat_id);

            try {
                execute(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }else if (command.equals("/subscribe")) { // подписка на прогноз погоды
                Database database = new Database();
                try {
                    database.WriteDB(message.getChatId(),
                            message.getChat().getUserName(),
                            message.getChat().getFirstName(),
                            message.getChat().getLastName(),
                            message.getLocation().getLatitude(), //здесь значение параметра равно NULL
                            message.getLocation().getLongitude()); //здесь значение параметра равно NULL
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SendMessage sendMsg = new SendMessage();
                sendMsg.setChatId(chat_id).setText("Thanks for subscribe!!!");
                try {
                    execute(sendMsg);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

               try {
                    execute(sendMsg);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (command.equals("/unsubscribe")) { // отписка от прогноза погоды

        }
    }
}....................
```

Не могу сообразить как реализовать связь между отправкой текущего местоположения и командой подписки("/subscribe").

Comment: Не очень понятно в чем проблема. Вы хотите чтобы после команды пользователю раз в какой-то период времени приходил прогноз погоды для заданных координат? Если так, то вроде не вижу проблемы, создаете какой-нибудь класс-сервис, который в отдельном потоке выполняет то, что нужно. Например, достает из базы список пользователей с координатами, для которых последняя рассылка выполнялась больше, чем заданный промежуток времени, рассылаете всем, обновляете время рассылки. Периодичность можно задать с помощью какой-нибудь библиотеки, коих довольно много, взять хотя бы Spring с `@Scheduled`

Comment: С алгоритмом рассылки погоды в принципе все понятно. Не получается записать текущие данные о местоположении в базу. При команде "/subscribe", latitude и longitude пустые.

Comment: А вы делаете запрос за геолокационные данные? В `KeyboardButton` нужно выставить `requestLocation` в `true`.

Comment: Нет. Геолокацию отправляю стандартными методами Telegram, а проверяю в условии if (message.hasLocation()).

Comment: Скорее всего нужно делать запрос, потому что без ведома пользователя клиент не будет передавать его геолокационные данные.

Comment: Дело в том что условие if (message.hasLocation()) работает и присылает погоду в ответ через стандартную отправку локации. Я думаю что можно как то реализовать это и при подписке, но не могу сообразить)